# HTTP Request on JMeter does not return a response from some sites

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I wonder if someone can provide some guidance on why I am not getting a response in a timely manner for a HTTP Request I am running, details are below:

I am a complete beginner with JMeter, trying to learn as I use it.

I ran a couple of smoke tests on my first project, I setup a HTTP GET Request Sampler to url asda.com
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqfYq.png)

and another sampler to url tesco.com [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsnjG.png)

I get a response returned for asda.com within a second or two but I do not get any response from tesco.com [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqrxv.png)

The timer in top right keeps counting up until I actually stop the test manually [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VdB3.png)

Once I manually stop the test, naturally there is a result in the Listener for tesco.com[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/583Rs.png)

Note: this is what my Test Plan looks like [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtSZM.png)

Things I have tried on the tesco.com Sampler:
Adding HTTPS in the Protocol field
Running with 'Redirect Automatically' ticked/unticked

I can navigate to url [www.tesco.com](http://www.tesco.com) via browser so I know the site is up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `tesco.com` and `www.tesco.com` are different servers
2. Your browser doesn't execute simple plain [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request, it adds some headers like:

   - [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)
   - [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)
   - [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)
   - etc.

   so given you add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send the same headers your browser sends - you should get the same response.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)